# Read in String From File, Split by Tab in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am missing something obvious.  I have a string that is tab separated in a text file.  I read it into an argument

Here is what it looks like in the text file:

```
hello   world   foo bar
```

So each of those words has a tab between them in the text file.

I read it into a variable

```
line = ""
File.open("some_file", "r+") do |file|
  line = file.gets
end
```

Now I simply want to split up the words by the tab separation:

```
word1, word2, word3, word4 = line.split("\t")
```

However what is happening is that it is putting ALL the words in the first variable, leaving the other variables with nil

```
p word1
=> "hello   world   foo bar"

p word2
=> nil

p word3
=> nil

p word4
=> nil
```

What am I missing? A word should be within each of those variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your string does not contain `"\t"` in it (but rather spaces):

```
words = 'hello world foo bar'
words.split(' ')
#=> ["hello", "world", "foo", "bar"]
```

If it really would contain tabs:

```
"hello\tworld"
```

you then would indeed be able to split it as intended:

```
"hello\tworld".split("\t")
#=> ["hello", "world"]
```

Comment: ahh, I just figured it out.  The issue was that I created the `.txt` with my text editor (which is rubymine).  I must have preferences set within rubymine that when I press tab, it actually enters a couple of spaces, so no tabs were actually entered in the text file.  I fixed it by just opening the `.txt` file in TextEdit and put the tabs in there.  That did the trick. My code worked just fine after that.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: @Neil yep, it's spaces when it's spaces :) Good to know you've made it work